# Kotlin MVP implementation issue with generics

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, android-mvp

Trying to implement a simple MVP structure with Kotlin,
here are my base classes:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<P : BasePresenter<BaseView>> : BaseView, AppCompatActivity() {
//...
}

abstract class BasePresenter<V : BaseView>  {
//...
}

interface BaseView {
//...
}
```

And trying to use this structure with

```
class DummyActivity : BaseActivity<DummyPresenter>(), DummyView.View {
//...
}

class DummyPresenter : BasePresenter<DummyView.View>(), DummyView.UserActionListener {
//...
}

interface DummyView {

interface View : BaseView {
    fun displayLoading()
}

interface UserActionListener {
    fun onButtonClicked()
 }
}
```

However I am getting an error in DummyActivity, BaseActivity() as:

[image: error]

I am assuming there is something to be fixed in BaseActivity about generics, however I can not figure out what.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First class in your first code block should be defined as

```
abstract class BaseActivity<P : BasePresenter<out BaseView>> : BaseView, AppCompatActivity() {
//...
}
```

Key being the `out` modifier on `BaseView`.

Comment: I'm afraid this breaks the invocation of attachView(view: V) method I have in the BasePresenter as it says the method expects Nothing.

Comment: The code as you posted compiles as soon as I add the `out` modifier as stated in my answer. Could you please provide the full code?